# Alter Column Check error

Tags: mysql, sql, constraints, alter

I have a column in SQL that I need to add an additional check constraint to. Currently the column is set to,

```
PropType Varchar(23) Check(PropType In('Potential Property','Vacant Property','Work-In-Progress-Property','Sold Property','Rental Property'))Not Null;
```

With this alter statement i am trying to change the character limit to 50 as well as add an additional check figure 'Vacant Property,Work-In-Progress-Property',

```
alter table property
alter column PropType Varchar(50) Check(PropType In('Potential Property','Vacant Property','Work-In-Progress-Property','Vacant Property,Work-In-Progress-Property','Sold Property','Rental Property'))Not Null;
```

I am getting this error,

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>       Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Check'.

Does anyone have any idea why? this is literally the exact same statement i used to make the table except it uses 50 characters and has an extra check figure. I tried using 'Add Constraint' in front of check and i have no luck.

Comment: You do know that check constraints are ignored in MySQL, right? So, even if you correct the syntax, MySQL still will not honor the validation.

Comment: If you want a column that can only contain a list of strings, you have to use `ENUM`, not `VARCHAR` with `CHECK` clause. It's also stored more efficiently, since it implements it as an integer index into the list of strings. However, there are many database experts who say ENUM should practically never be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
alter table property alter column PropType Varchar(50) NOT NULL; 

alter table property add Check(PropType In('Potential Property','Vacant Property','Work-In-Progress-Property','Vacant Property,Work-In-Progress-Property','Sold Property','Rental Property'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try **modify**:::

```
alter table property MODIFY column PropType Varchar(50) Check(PropType In('Potential Property','Vacant Property','Work-In-Progress-Property','Vacant Property,Work-In-Progress-Property','Sold Property','Rental Property'))Not Null;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! i tried that and got this error. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'MODIFY'.

Comment: maybe i can disable the constraint and then add a new one in somehow

Comment: What constraint do you want to disable? MySQL ignores the `CHECK` clause.